# CSS styling for autoscale nested tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

The problem in following. I have some `div` which is presents the parent container. Inside that `div` I have a nested `table`, that can be scrolled. The parent `div` is stratched. So, when I resize my `div` container I want to resize the nested `table` too. The code is presented bellow don't support this. How can I do it? Maybe I need different structure of all document?

Important note - I need solution without using `JavaScript`.

**HTML code**:

```
<div id="main_container">
<table id="wrapper_table">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>test content</td>
            <td>test content</td>
          </tr>
          ...  
        </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS code**:

```
#main_container {  
  position:fixed;
  top:0px; 
  height: 200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  top:30px;    
}

#wrapper_table {
    width:100%;    
}

.wrapper {
  overflow:scroll;
  height:100%;
}

.cell {
    height: 200px;   
}
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#main_container').resizable({handles: 'n,e'});
});
```

The fiddle here - [**http://jsfiddle.net/y4Bk2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4Bk2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Css resize property. But this will not supported by internet explorer and opera. You need to add

```
#main_container {  
 position:fixed;
 top:0px; 
 height: 200px;
 border:1px solid black;
 top:30px;
 overflow:auto;
 resize:both;    
  }
```

and add this

```
#wrapper_table::-webkit-scrollbar{
display:none;}
```

Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7fPBX/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple option for this since you're already using the jQuery UI resizable widget.

Use [alsoResize](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize)

> One or more elements to resize synchronously with the resizable
>   element.

Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/y4Bk2/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#main_container').resizable({handles: 'n,e',  alsoResize: '.wrapper table'});
});
```